# "at the start of a project" vs "at a start of a project"

Tags: grammar, articles

Which article is correct in the following sentence (if any):

> Requirements must be defined at **the/a** start of a project.

If "the" is correct, then could you please explain why? Why do we need an article here at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'The' is necessary and required, because there is only one start of a project, and unique items are preceded by the definite article. You may find websites such as Grammar Monster useful:

> The definite article is the word "the." It is used before a noun to
> define it as something specific (e.g., something previously mentioned
> or known, something unique, or something being identified by the
> speaker).

[Definite article](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/definite_article.htm)